# Perl parsing hash of hashes of arrays

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse .dmp files that contain a hash of hashes of arrays. I need to get the key value pair from the arrays so I can store them into a mysql database. I've tried several methods but can't get it to work properly.

The code in the files looks like this: 
I need to store one hash of arrays per row in the database

```
$VAR={  'booktodo-yzi07mwp-1102021083' => {
    '_modtime' => [
      1102021143
    ],
    'version' => [
      '25'
    ],
    'pubnum' => [
      '2332'
    ],
    '_status' => [
      'active'
    ],
    '_user' => [
      'lcm'
    ],
    'description' => [
      'Revise trademarks'
    ]
  },
  'booktodo-p8ekw9d3-1104950962' => {
    '_modtime' => [
      1104950986
    ],
    'version' => [
      '3.0'
    ],
    'pubnum' => [
      'S-2326-30'
    ],
    '_status' => [
      'active'
    ],
    '_user' => [
      'malz'
    ],
    'description' => [
      'Send out a request for install guide changes'
    ]
  },
```

This is what I have so far. I am just trying to access the elements in the arrays
Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/modules/lib";

my %VAR;

#open DMP;
open (FILE, "<./booktodo.dmp") or die "could not open file: $!";
undef $/;


#store evaled data in %VAR hash
%VAR = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
eval %VAR;

foreach my $loop (keys %VAR){
    foreach my $hash (keys $VAR{$loop}){
         for my $i (0..$#{$VAR{$loop}}){
                print "$i= $VAR{$loop}[$i]\n";
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show code that you have tried so that we can suggest changes.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your code: first, **`use warnings`**! Second, you are reading the file content into `%VAR`. With `warnings`, you'd get a 'odd number of elements' warning. Because of `undef $\` you slurp it all into the first key of `%VAR`. (What about your `File::Slurp`?). Try `print Dumper \%VAR` and you'll see what I mean. See [@user5402's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12359677/1331451) for how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
...
my $contents = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my $hash_of_hashes_of_arrays = eval $contents;
...
```

Note that you are now working with a reference to a hash.
To iterate over it:

```
for my $key (keys %$hash_of_hashes_of_arrays) {
  my $hash = $hash_of_hashes_of_arrays->{$key};
  for my $key2 (keys %$hash) {
    my $array = $hash->{$key2};
    for my $i (0..$#$array) {
      print "$i: $$array[$i]\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try to understand what you did here and then give it a try.

Comment: A little bit of explanation would be nice so the OP can see where the problem lies.

Comment: You should point out the security risk of using string [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).